# Impossible to display emojis with their unicode in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, emoji

I would like to display emojis in my Angular application. I found this https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_smileys.asp which works in html vanilla. But when i try it into my Angular application it only display the little rectangle for "unknown character".
My application is in Angular 7

I already tried to sanitize it i saw this in multiple problem like mine, but it doesn't work, and it's not really clean code anyway.

```html
<div class="collapse" id="collapseSmiley">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{ domSanitize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('&#128513;') }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expect to have a emoji, and i only have a rectangle "unknown char"

Comment: Hi, for cleaner code create a custom directive that handles emoji characters

Comment: yes but that was just for trying. I'll do cleaner code when i'll have working code... Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So without going into detail on how unicode and everything goes together with angular vs html in order for you to just get going use following:

**component:**

```
<p emoji=""></p>
```

**directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[emoji]'
})
export class EmojiDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('emoji') emoji: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.textContent += this.emoji;
  }
}
```

and basically copy the [emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f628) of your choice from the browser column in order to get concatenated with your text

**or:**

simply create your own strings that matches the unicode like so:

**component:**

```
<p emoji="smile"></p>
```

**directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[emoji]'
})
export class EmojiDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('emoji') emoji: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.textContent += this.getEmoji(this.emoji);
  }

  getEmoji(uniEmoji: string) {
    let emoji: string;
    switch(uniEmoji){
      case 'smile': emoji = '\uD83D\uDE42'
    }

    return emoji
  }

}
```

Comment: @BenoitBonavia don't post it as comment (remove it...), update your POST question with your directive code instead

Comment: @BenoitBonavia and by looking at your code the unicode `&#128540;` you are putting is not going to work, you have to use other format as the example i showed or simply do it as the first example i gave you

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same problem, but apparently, if you just copy and paste the emoticon straight inside the string it will show up in the browser (like ), but not if I place for instance "&#x1F308".

Comment: Copy Paste worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used it this way and it worked. :p

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
   
   Swal.fire({
      title: 'Logout Successful',
      text: '',
      icon: 'success',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      showCancelButton: false
    })
```

> https://html-css-js.com/html/character-codes/
>
>  **You can copy the emojis from above website directly(which I included in "text: <*here*>").**